# opening a file in terminal vim make the message press enter or enter command to appear

Tags: command-line, vim

If I open a file in VIM either through `:e <filename>` or clicking the <kbd>O</kbd> key in NERDTree side window or searching and selecting a file with FZF from inside vim makes, I see the message

> press enter or enter command

(I see this message in Italian, and have translated it, so the wording may be slightly off.)

If I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> the file is opened and everything works fine.

This happens for all the files contained in a specific folder an in its subfolders, but not outside of that particular folder. I checked the owners and permissions and everything seems right.

All this started two days ago. Before then, `:e <filename>` would just open a file without asking anything more.

Why does this happen? How can I bring back the normal vim behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

After a deeper research I find out that the problem was with some kind of files and not with the folder after all, the problem seems to be that I have the Ale plugin in vim and activated `let g:ale_completion_enabled = 1` in my .vimrc, this makes the message to appear every time I open a file that Ale knows (js,php) but not with files it don't know.

I commented the line in .vimrc and everything is back to normal